# reading sqlite database via mqtt to an mqtt broker using c

Tags: c, sqlite, mqtt

I want to read a sqlite3 db file for sending data from an embedded device over a data connection via mqtt to an mqtt broker in c language.

i m getting error "Failed to connect, return code 5"

can anyone please help me out for correcting this code

thanks in advance

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <MQTTClient.h>
 #include <sqlite3.h>
 #define ADDRESS     "tcp:localhost:1883"
 #define CLIENTID    "......"
 #define USERNAME    "....."
 #define PASSWORD    "....."
 #define TOPIC       "..."
 #define QOS         1
 #define TIMEOUT     10000L

 static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char* argv[],char   **azColName)
{
int i;
 for(i = 0; i<argc; i++) {
  printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
 }

  }
int main() {

int rc;
 MQTTClient client;
 MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts =   MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
 MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
 MQTTClient_deliveryToken token;

 MQTTClient_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID,
        MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);
 conn_opts.username = USERNAME;
  conn_opts.password = PASSWORD;
  conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
  conn_opts.cleansession = 1;

   if ((rc = MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
   {
      printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   pubmsg.qos = QOS;
   pubmsg.retained = 0;

  sqlite3 *db;
  char *zErrMsg = 0;
  char *sql;
  const char* data = "Callback function called";

   rc = sqlite3_open("db/dht.db", &db);
   sql = "SELECT * from table";
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);

   MQTTClient_publishMessage(client, TOPIC, &pubmsg, &token);
    printf("Waiting for up to %d seconds for publication of %s\n"
    "on topic %s for client with ClientID: \n",
    (int)(TIMEOUT/1000), TOPIC, CLIENTID);
     rc = MQTTClient_waitForCompletion(client, token, TIMEOUT);
     printf("Message with delivery token %d delivered\n", token); 
  sqlite3_close(db);
  return 0 ;
  }
```

Comment: Your URI (ADDRESS) is wrong `tcp://localhost:1883` not `tcp:localhost:1883`

Comment: Have you looked up what return code 5 means? It is documented in `MQTTClient.h`

Comment: @hardillb The first one is a typo ...sorry for that                                                                   In   MQTTClient.h I found the  following ..                                                                                                                    define MQTTCLIENT_BAD_UTF8_STRING -5
/**
 * Return code: A NULL parameter has been supplied when this is invalid.

Comment: No, that's `-5` not `5`, look at the doc (in the comment just before) for `MQTTClient_connect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Paho C [doc](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTClient/html/_m_q_t_t_client_8h.html#aaa8ae61cd65c9dc0846df10122d7bd4e)

> **MQTTClient_connect()**
>
> ```
> int MQTTClient_connect(MQTTClient handle, MQTTClient_connectOptions* options)
> ```
>
> This function attempts to connect a previously-created client (see
>   MQTTClient_create()) to an MQTT server using the specified options. If
>   you want to enable asynchronous message and status notifications, you
>   must call MQTTClient_setCallbacks() prior to MQTTClient_connect().
>
> *Parameters*
>
> - *handle*   A valid client handle from a successful call to MQTTClient_create().
> - *options*  A pointer to a valid MQTTClient_connectOptions structure.
>
> *Returns*
>
> MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS if the client successfully connects to the server.
>   An error code is returned if the client was unable to connect to the
>   server. Error codes greater than 0 are returned by the MQTT protocol:
>
> - 1: Connection refused: Unacceptable protocol version
> - 2: Connection refused: Identifier rejected
> - 3: Connection refused: Server unavailable
> - 4: Connection refused: Bad user name or password
> - 5: Connection refused: Not authorized
> - 6-255: Reserved for future use

A return code of 5 means "Not authorized", this implies your username/password are wrong.